# How can I sum my monthly columns into quarter and annual columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Started using python a few days ago, been having a relatively okay time until I ran into this issue. I have a dataframe with some numerical data separated into YYYYMM columns.

For example:

|  | 201003 | 201004 | 201005 | 201006 | 201007 | 201008 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 11 | 14 | 22 | 10 | 19 |
| B | 14 | 19 | 20 | 22 | 26 | 11 |

The example data above goes from 201003 to 201008, but the data depends on which years and months the user would like to pull (201006-201303 could be another pull for example).

Is there a way I can sum the columns without writing specifically I want to sum 201004, 201005, 201006 for 2010q2?

Further, can I turn all the sums into different quarterly/annual columns in the dataframe?

For quarterly, I'm entirely at a loss of what I should do.

For annual I used the column names to make a list, then rounded those names down to just years (2010, 2011, etc.) Then I found a code on stackoverflow that would create a new variable using the list of years. It had map and regenx in it. I can't provide you with the full code though because I erased it well before I decided to post this question here on stackoverflow.

Sorry. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I have multiple rows, not just one.

Comment: This is just not the right way to organize this data.  Consider having a date column with an actual datetime object with the first day of the month, and a column with your symbol, so each row has one datapoint.  Now you can do groupings by quarter or by year with no troubles.  You can then transpose the data if you want to display it like above.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over how the data comes in.

Comment: Maybe not, but you can change it.  That's the whole point here.

Comment: Check out the User Guide: [Time series / date functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html), especially sections "Converting to timestamps" and "Resampling".

Answer (score 0):

if you use `df.melt()`, you can convert those columns into rows, which can help you then break apart the year-month into two pieces.

```py
df = df.melt()
df
   variable  value
0    201004     10
1    201004     10
2    201005     14
...
```

From here, use df['variable'].str to split the strings apart based on number of chars.

```py
df['year'] = df['variable'].str[:4]
df['month'] = df['variable'].str[4:]
```

For quarters, you can make a mapping from the month values to the quarters, and then use `df.map()`

```py
month_quarter_map = {'01':1,'02':1,'03':1,'04':2...}

df['quarter'] = df['month'].map(month_quarter_map)
```

Comment: Why melt instead of transpose? Why continue using strings instead of datetimes, which let you resample?

Comment: I have multiple rows, is melting still a good option?

Comment: both of wjandrea's points sounds great - transpose is probably better, esp if you have multiple rows (although i can't copy-paste your data table trivially, and moving on to other things now). and yea, you should make them dates rather than keeping strings

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

`groupby` + `axis=1` with period data of columns

```
freq = 'Q' 
grp = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%Y%m').to_period(freq)
out = df.groupby(grp, axis=1).sum()
```

out:

```
    2010Q1  2010Q2  2010Q3
A   10      47      29
B   14      61      37
```

i made variable `freq`, so you can easily change frequency. if you change `freq` to `'Y'`, you can get yearly sum.

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'201003': {'A': 10, 'B': 14},
         '201004': {'A': 11, 'B': 19},
         '201005': {'A': 14, 'B': 20},
         '201006': {'A': 22, 'B': 22},
         '201007': {'A': 10, 'B': 26},
         '201008': {'A': 19, 'B': 11}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```